# Optimize select query on huge tables?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I am trying to grabs specific rows in an Oracle database given index column values. I am selecting the index columns followed by the entire row data for ease of processing. There are roughly 150 million rows on the table and I am selecting roughly 100 - 200 thousand. I am using NVL() to replace null values in my IN clause because I am creating these statements dynamically in JAVA. The IN clause is chunked into 1000 index chunks pieced together by OR's to avoid "maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000" error.

As you can imagine, this query is taking a very long time to run. Is there anything I can do to optimize this query but keep the same functionality? (disregard the index values as they are just an example)

```
select INDEX_COLUMN_A, INDEX_COLUMN_B, INDEX_COLUMN_C, TABLE.* from TABLE     
Where (NVL(INDEX_COLUMN_A,''), NVL(INDEX_COLUMN_B,''), NVL(INDEX_COLUMN_C,'')) 
IN (('1','1','1'), ('2','2','2'), ... ('1000','1000','1000')) 
OR (NVL(INDEX_COLUMN_A,''), NVL(INDEX_COLUMN_B,''), NVL(INDEX_COLUMN_C,'')) 
IN (('1001','1001','1001'), ('1002','1002','1002'), ... ('2000','2000','2000')) 
OR...
```

Comment: Wrapping an indexed column inside a function call like `NVL` effectively prevents Oracle from using the index. You could create a function-based index or alternatively eliminate the `NVL` call.

Comment: The indexes might not even be useful if you're selecting 1/1000 rows of the table; a full table scan may be faster here anyways.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Ahh I didn't realize that NVL would ruin the indexing. That is most unfortunate. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Empty strings used in your query (i mean `''`) treated by Oracle as nulls. So expressions like `nvl(column_x,'')` means nothing because literally equivalent to `if column_x is null return null else return column_x`.

Comment: Doesn't Oracle treat empty strings as NULL? But why do you think you need the `NVL`, NULL is always different from '1'. Additionally huge IN-lists kill performance (did you check the time to parse/optimize it), you might better load the values into a table and then join.

Comment: Where do you get values for `in` clause?

Comment: These values are pulled from another database which I am comparing against. Having no nulls is not certain, hence I was going to try to use NVL to get past that, but the hit on performance is too great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely avoid `nvl()` from condition if there are no possibility of encountering `null` in test values like `('1','1','1')` or `('2000','2000','2000')`:

```
select 
  INDEX_COLUMN_A, INDEX_COLUMN_B, INDEX_COLUMN_C, 
  TABLE.* 
from 
  TABLE     
where 
  (INDEX_COLUMN_A, INDEX_COLUMN_B, INDEX_COLUMN_C) 
  in (
    ('1','1','1'), 
    ('2','2','2'), 
    ...,
    ('1000','1000','1000')
  ) 
  OR 
  (INDEX_COLUMN_A, INDEX_COLUMN_B, INDEX_COLUMN_C) 
  in (
    ('1001','1001','1001'), 
    ('1002','1002','1002'),
     ...,
    ('2000','2000','2000')
  ) 
  or
  ...
```

Also, expression like `a in (x1,x2) or a in (x3,x4)` means `((a=x1 or a=x2) or (a=x3 or a=x4))`.  Brackets in such situation may be omitted without consequences: `(a=x1 or a=x2 or a=x3 or a=x4)` which may be shortened with `in` expression as `a in (x1, x2, x3, x4)`. Therefore initial query (if there are no nulls in values to test for) are same as following:

```
select 
  INDEX_COLUMN_A, INDEX_COLUMN_B, INDEX_COLUMN_C, 
  TABLE.* 
from 
  TABLE     
where 
  (INDEX_COLUMN_A, INDEX_COLUMN_B, INDEX_COLUMN_C) 
  in (
    ('1','1','1'), 
    ('2','2','2'), 
    ...,
    ('1000','1000','1000')
    ...,
    ('1001','1001','1001'), 
    ('1002','1002','1002'),
     ...,
    ('2000','2000','2000')
  )
```

**P.S.**

`a in (x,y,z)` is just a shortcut for set of equality relations connected by `or` :`((a=x) or (a=y or (a=z))` and `null` never equals `null`, so expression `null in (x,y,z)` never returns `true` regardless of `x`, `y` and `z` values. So if you really need to handle `null` values then expressions must be changed to something like `nvl(a,'some_never_encountered_value') in (nvl('1', 'some_never_encountered_value'), nvl('2','some_never_encountered_value'),...)`. But at this case you can't use simple index on a table. It's possible to build functional index to handle such expressions, but this is a very different story.

**P.P.S.**
If columns contains numbers it must be tested against numbers: instead of `('1','1','1')` you should use `(1,1,1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am not sure if I can ensure there is no possibility of nulls, hence my initial use of NVL. I needed to keep the Or's in because without them, I got 'maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error'. Lastly, does testing numbers against numbers as opposed to string to number improve performance? or is that simply for good coding etiquette?

Answer (score 1):

Using `or` in `where` clause also can prevent using index. You can replace query like

```
select *
  from table
 where <condition1> or <condition2>
```

with

```
select *
  from table
 where <condition1>
 union all
select *
  from table
 where <condition2>
```

The second query, in turn, can produce duplicated rows (it depends on data). To prevent duplication you can use `union` instead of `union all`, but using `union` also can provoke performance issues. You need to make a number of experiments, which way is the best in your situation.

Comment: Running *roughly 100 - 200 thousand* SELECT/UNION instead?

Comment: Does using OR really prevent use of the index? I was using that to prevent 'maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 error'.

Comment: @JoshKni8 Not always, but sometimes can prevent. Mostly when you have conditions like `a > 100 or b < 200`. In your case (with `in (1, 2, 3, ...)`) index will be used.